# How to create particles in Unity at a point of impact

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm working on a Pong project as a learning tool to help me get used to Unity as a development studio. What I want to do is create a Particle System every time the ball hits either paddle. So I put a particle system as a child under each paddle, and made it so it called that particle system every time the ball made contact with the paddle in C#. It doesn't work, and I want to make it so it calls the particle system at the point of impact between the ball and the paddle. Here's the code I currently have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExplosionScript : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject explosionParticle;

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.collider.CompareTag ("Player")) {
        Explode ();
    }
}

void Explode () {
    Instantiate (explosionParticle, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
}
}
```

This code is attached to the ball GameObject.

[image: Hierarchy for Scene]

Comment: i am trying this in my own game code.

Comment: Okay. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`explosionParticle.Play();` after instantiating.

typically I create a separate `ParticleSystem gameobject` and not a child so I can prefab or modify it. Then I declare 
`public ParticleSystem explosion;` then attach the ParticleSystem gameobject to the `ball` `explosion` property.

In code I would do just this

`Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
 explosion.Play();`

Comment: I'm sorry, `but in explosion.Play();`, where does the `.Play();` come from? It's invalid in my code.

Comment: `public GameObject explosionParticle;` make it
`public ParticleSystem explosionParticle;`